# Abp.io Commercial - Identity Module Localization

Tags: angular, .net-core, abp

I'm unable to find documentation nor figure out how to Localize Name, Surname in the identity module to first name, last name.  We did not pay for source code.  UI is angular.  User Screen of ABP.io commercial.  I've tried a number of combinations in the aspnet-core en.json file:

```
    {
  "Culture": "en",
  "Texts": {
    "AbpIdentity:Name": "First Name",
    "AbpIdentity:Surname": "Last Name",
  }
}
```

as well as

```
{
  "Culture": "en",
  "Texts": {
    "AbpIdentity::DisplayName:Name": "First Name",
    "AbpIdentity::DisplayName:Surname": "Last Name",
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "Culture": "en",
  "Texts": {
    "Name": "First Name",
    "Surname": "Last Name",
  }
}
```

[User Edit Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhVE0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found you can set this from the Language Text Section in the UI.  Still wasn't able to get it to work using the Localization file in the .net-core project.